# what does a forward slash denote in ipv6 addressing system TCP/IP

Tags: ipv6

ipv6 is of 128 bit address, we define our address `fe088::/32`. What does `/32`, `/64` denote in the address

```
for example     2001:420::**/64**
```

?

Comment: The same as in IPv4. Off-topic.

Comment: `fe088::`? What is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stateless address autoconfiguration (`SLAAC`) to work, subnets require a `/64` address block as defined in `RFC 4291` section 2.5.1. Local Internet registries get assigned at least `/32` blocks, which they divide among ISPs. The obsolete `RFC 3177` recommended the assignment of a `/48` to end consumer sites. This was replaced by `RFC 6177`, which "recommends giving home sites significantly more than a single `/64`, but does not recommend that every home site be given a `/48` either." `/56s` are specifically considered. It remains to be seen if ISPs will honor this recommendation; for example, during initial trials Comcast customers have been given a single `/64` network.